# Поиск часто повторяющихся элементов в массиве c#

Tags: массивы, winforms, числа, textbox, повторы

На форме есть несколько текстбоксов, объединённые в массив tb, в каждом из них введены числа через пробел. Не получается найти во всех текстбоксах сразу самое часто повторяющееся число и количество повторений. Вот мой код, здесь подсчёт происходит по нажатию кнопки:

C#

```
private void Searsh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TextBox tb in Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x =>         x.Enabled == true)) // Проверяет, активны ли текстбоксы
    {
        var sorted = tb.Text.GroupBy(x => x).Select(g => new {     Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
        var odno = sorted.First();
        Chisla.Text = odno.Value.ToString();
        Povt.Text = odno.Count.ToString();
    }
}
```

sorted - колекция повторяющихся чисел
tb - массив текстбоксов
Value - часто повторяющееся число
Count - количество повторений
Chicla - лэйбл, в котором показывается самое часто повторяющееся число
Povt - лэйбл, в который передаётся кол-во повторений

Да, и мне нужно ещё, чтобы исключалась ошибка (вдруг одинаковых чисел нет). Ну и если таких чисел несколько, отсортировать их по количеству повторений и просмотреть их. Есть способ, но не уверен, что он правильный:
Код:

```
if (sorted.Length >= 2)
{
    var dva = sorted.Skip(1).Take(1); // Пропустить первое     число и выбрать второе
    Chisla.Text = dva.First().Key;
    Povt.Text = dva.First().Count.ToString();
}
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Словарик с числами и их количеством
        Dictionary<int, int> repeats = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        // Флаг, определяющий есть ли хоть один повтор
        bool isRepeat = false;

        // Пробегаем по всем полям
        foreach (TextBox tb in Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(t => t.Enabled == true))
        {
            var numbers = tb.Text.Split(' ');

            // Пробегаем по всем числам
            foreach (var numb in numbers.Select(int.Parse))
            {
                if (repeats.ContainsKey(numb))
                {
                    repeats[numb] += 1;
                    isRepeat = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    repeats[numb] = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!isRepeat)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Повторов нет!");
            return;
        }

        listBox1.Items.Add("Число\tПовторов");

        foreach (var item in repeats.OrderByDescending(v => v.Value))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}\t{1}", item.Key, item.Value));
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]